# Rails has_many relation: a look at object_ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, ruby-on-rails-2, objectid

Something strange is happening in Rails 2.3.14. Any ideas why the following happens?

### Example

Suppose we have classes like

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :prices
end

class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Then in a `irb` session the following happens.

```
>> a = Article.first
=> #<Article id: 980190962>
>> a.prices.first.object_id
=> 97498070
>> a.prices.first.object_id
=> 97470500
>> a.prices.first.object_id
=> 97451010
>> a.valid?
=> true
>> a.prices.first.object_id
=> 97374790
>> a.prices.first.object_id
=> 97374790
```

So at first the `object_id` changes each time the record is accessed (yes, it's always the same one). Later after a call to `#valid?` this behavior stops. Instead everything is fine. You get the same object on each call.

### Why is this important?

Let's assume you add a validation to `Price`

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :amount
end
```

Then you want to change a price of an article.

```
>> a = Article.first
=> #<Article id: 980190962>
>> p = a.prices.first
=> #<Price id: 280438907, amount: 1.0, article_id: 980190962>
>> p.amount = nil # oops, accidentally we assigned nil
=> nil
>> p.valid?
=> false
>> a.valid?
=> true
```

What's that? The price is invalid, but the article is not? This shouldn't have happend, because by default the `:validate`-option of `has_many` is set to `true`. This happens because of the changing `object_id`s

Answer (score 0):

Every new context(request/response) will regenerate the object IDs. As you are running the query `a.prices.first.object_id` it will hit the query to get the first price every time and as each hit will generate new object IDs.

But in second case you have extracted first price into a instance variable and working on that so no new request/response is going to database hence it is giving same object IDS.